# Second layer of conditional statement within inline condition react

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to check the trigger status if it is new, and after that i need to check another condition and based on which i need to display tagone or tagtwo.

I have been trying to find inline documentation for this.

```
<modalscrolling  onClose={this.props.toggleModal} open={openModal} 
 trigger={isNew ? 
<sometag /> : 
<TagOne  />}>
<TagTwp />}
>
```

the other approach i am trying is to send it to a different function. Any suggestions to deal with this :)

Comment: Or you can assign component to this variable before return at render ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can have nested ternary operators as following,

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
export default function App() {
  var isNew = true;
  var tag = 1;
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {isNew ? (
        tag === 1 ? (
          <span>tag1</span>
        ) : (
          <span>tag2</span>
        )
      ) : (
        <span>notnew</span>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-shape-r64i8

but i would suggest extract inside teranary operation to another function component which takes "tag" as input. it helps to extend your code easily and make it more readable.

**App.js with another after refactoring**

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const AnotherCompoent = ({ tag }) => {
  return tag === 1 ? <span>tag1</span> : <span>tag2</span>;
};

export default function App() {
  var isNew = true;
  var tag = 1;
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {isNew ? <AnotherCompoent tag={tag} /> : <span>notnew</span>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-hertz-1ou77

Comment: i had to switch the order, but it worked beautifully. The secondary concept (Another component) is a great - possible the better approach, i have too many parameters to switch and hence i decide to go with the first one.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
<modalscrolling  onClose={this.props.toggleModal} open={openModal} 
 trigger={isNew ? <SomeTag /> : secondLevelCondition ? <TagOne  /> :<TagTwp /> }
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ternary operator is better option as it helps understand the component markup. If the conditional parts are big, convert them to seperate functional components.

Answer (score 0):

`trigger= { isNew ? <sometag/> : { anothercond ?  <TagOne  /> : <TagTwo/> }}`.

Is this what you're looking for?